# Error on doInBackground, on method getText and method makeHttpRequest

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I create a program from [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

I get some error on this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String id = id_anggota.getText().toString();
        String nama = nama_anggota.getText().toString();
        String kelamin = jenis_kelamin.getText().toString();
        String kls = kelas.getText().toString();
        String tanggal = tanggal_daftar.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_anggota", id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_anggota", nama));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis_kelamin", kelamin));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", kls));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal_daftar", tanggal));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);
```

I get 2 kind of error:

1. On getText method `id_anggota.getText()` must be called from the UI Thread.
2. On `makeHttpRequest` method cannot resolved.

What solutions can I do for this problem?

**Update:**

I use some library:

1. httpclient-android-4.3.3.jar
2. httpcore-4.4.5.jar
3. com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1

Comment: `id_anggota.getText()` should be called in `onPreExecute()`

Comment: Did you give me an example please

Comment: `AsyncTask` has `onPreExecute()` method. It runs on UI thread before performing `doInBackground`. So you can move some codes that need to be run on UI thread to `onPreExecute()`

Comment: When I move `String id = id_anggota.getText().toString();` to onPreExecute(), It make cannot solve id on `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_anggota", id));`

Comment: It's work. Thank you very much.

Comment: See my answer below. If it works, could you please accept it as the right answer?

Comment: If you can give me solution for "makeHttpRequest method cannot resolved", I will make you the right answer :D

Comment: What is jsonParser in your code? Where is that JsonParser class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122971/discussion-between-d-aji-pratama-and-top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `AsyncTask` please declare some variables:

```
 private String id ;
 private String nama;
 private String kelamin ;
 private String kls;
 private String tanggal;
```

Then on `onPreExecute()` you can set values for them:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        id = id_anggota.getText().toString();
        nama = nama_anggota.getText().toString();
        kelamin = jenis_kelamin.getText().toString();
        kls = kelas.getText().toString();
        tanggal = tanggal_daftar.getText().toString();
    }
```

Finally on `doInBackground()`:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_anggota", id));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_anggota", nama));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis_kelamin", kelamin));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", kls));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal_daftar", tanggal));
```

`makeHttpRequest` can be found in `JSONParser` class [here](http://techlovejump.com/android-json-parser-from-url/) or [here](http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html)

Comment: Edit your answer with `makeHttpRequest` solution. so your answer can help another. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
String id = id_anggota.getText().toString();
String nama = nama_anggota.getText().toString();
String kelamin = jenis_kelamin.getText().toString();
String kls = kelas.getText().toString();
String tanggal = tanggal_daftar.getText().toString();
```

before `yourAsyncTask.execute()`.

Change `yourAsyncTask.execute()` to `yourAsyncTask.execute(id,nama,kelamin,kls,tanggal)`.

And in method doInBackground()

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_anggota", args[0]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_anggota", args[1]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis_kelamin", args[2]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", args[3]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tanggal_daftar", args[4]));
}
```

Comment: Did you give me an example please

Answer (score 1):

```
String id = id_anggota.getText().toString();
    String nama = nama_anggota.getText().toString();
    String kelamin = jenis_kelamin.getText().toString();
    String kls = kelas.getText().toString();
    String tanggal = tanggal_daftar.getText().toString();
```

This `getText()` interacts with the view, a `TextView` and all the views in android OS can only work in the UI(User Interface thread). `doInBackground()` makes a separate thread, a background thread like the name suggests. So getting the text from the `TextView` should always be from the UI thread which is managed by the android OS. So move the above code inside `onPreExecute()` which runs on the UI thread.

As far as `makeHttpRequest()` is concerned, just open the jar file and see if its has that `makeHttpRequest()` or not. You can decompile a jar file in the command prompt [like this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)

Comment: I am not saying that. I just said check the jar if it contains the `makeHttpRequest` method or not. I provided you with a link to see all the methods inside the jar. Check it out

Comment: I don't understand :|

Comment: ok, tell me one thing, what is jsonParser variable in your code. Where have you declared it?

Comment: `jsonParser` I declare it in MainActivity class

Comment: Post it in your question where you are declaring and using jsonParser

Comment: I found to solve my problem, I just use JSONParser with makeHttpRequest method, and it works. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Good, enjoy coding :)